# How can I run a shell script on multiple VMWare vm's created by terraform module?

Tags: bash, module, terraform, vmware

I am using this module to spin up multiple vm's on my vmware cluster, https://registry.terraform.io/modules/Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere/1.6.0, and I want to run a shell script on all of the vms after using a null resource. With what i currently have, it complains that the host was not given a string, which makes sense. Here is my null resource:

```
# main.tf
module "jenkins-linuxvm-centos7" {
  source = "Terraform-VMWare-Modules/vm/vsphere"
  ...
}

resource "null_resource" "vm" {
  triggers = {
    vm_ips = join(",", module.jenkins-linuxvm-centos7.Linux-ip)
  }

  # export TF_VAR_root_password=<pass>
  connection {
    type     = "ssh"
    host     = module.jenkins-linuxvm-centos7.Linux-ip
    user     = "root"
    password = var.vm_root_password
    port     = "22"
    agent    = false
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "resize_disk.sh"
    destination = "/tmp/resize_disk.sh"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "chmod +x /tmp/resize_disk.sh",
      "/tmp/resize_disk.sh"
    ]
  }
}
```

Do I need to use a dynamic block somehow? Or how can I modify `host     = module.jenkins-linuxvm-centos7.Linux-ip` to include all the hosts I want to run it on?

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it in a For_Each loop... Below is an example code where i am looping against the sql_var map variable. you will have to do it against the output of IPs --> module.jenkins-linuxvm-centos7.Linux-ip... you will be able to reference the IP of each machine as something like each.value i guess. I dont know how your output looks like, so guessing. If you are new to loops, here is one nice tuto.

https://blog.boltops.com/2020/10/04/terraform-hcl-loops-with-count-and-for-each

```
resource "null_resource" "instance" {
 
for_each = var.sql_var
  
    provisioner "local-exec" {
      command = "echo ${each.key} >> hello.txt"
  }
  
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but terraform doesn't seem to like using the output as its for_each value. getting this:
`
Error: Invalid for_each argument

  on main.tf line 52, in resource "null_resource" "vm":
  52:   for_each = toset(module.jenkins-linuxvm-centos7.Linux-ip)

The "for_each" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the for_each depends on.
`

Comment: Hey @nateph, to overcome this `for_each` issue, declare a boolean var & use that boolean var to decide whether you have to run the script on the servers or not. `for_each` and `count` cannot be applied on the resources which aren't present in the remote state. One option is to use `-target` as you quoted, the other is to define a dummy boolean var, & just override it when you want to run the script.